# How to justify this small angle approximation $\dot{\theta}^2=0$?

Tags: oscillators, approximations, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, linearized-theory

Suppose the equation of motion for some oscillating system takes the following form:

$$\ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta}^2\sin\theta+k^2\theta\cos\theta=0$$

Applying small angle approximation to $\theta$ gives $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ and $\cos\theta\approx1$,

$$\ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta}^2\theta+k^2\theta=0$$

But I am wondering if it is alright to set $\dot{\theta}^2=0$ so that the equation simplifies to

$$\ddot{\theta}+k^2\theta=0$$

If so, how can this approximation be justified?

Comment: Your approximation is only true if that physically is the case, however $\theta \sim 0$ as you know doesn't imply $\dot{\theta}\sim 0$

Comment: * some oscillating system* Which oscillating system? What physical reality underpins the DE? Try solve the DE with wolfram alpha.

Comment: You could rescale $\theta\rightarrow\epsilon\theta$ and expand your initial DE in orders of the small amplitude $\epsilon$, s.t. your final equation is the original DE up to order $\epsilon^2$, the next non-vanishing order beeing $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)$.

Comment: The origin (in velocity-phase space) is an equilibrium point of your ODE, which is why it makes sense to consider expanding the system about the equilibrium solution. Of course if you only want to consider up to first order, then you can drop several terms; see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/715769/203278) for a more detailed description of what it means to expand about equilibrium points. But keep in mind that this means you're only solving a linearized problem about the equilibrium solution.

Answer (score 4):

By drawing a phase plot you can more visually see where the approximations are valid. Define
\begin{align}
x&\equiv \theta\\
y&\equiv\dot\theta
\end{align}
This transforms your initial equation into the following first order differential equations:
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{\dot x\\\dot y}=\pmatrix{y\\-y^2\sin x-k^2x\cos x}
\end{align}
We can plot the vector on the right as a velocity field to see the dynamics. You are probably familiar with this. I use the following Mathematica code to do this:

```
range = 3;
expressions = {
   {{y, -k^2 x}, {y, -k^2 Sin[x]}},
   {{y, -y^2 x - k^2 x}, {y, -y^2 Sin[x] - k^2 x Cos[x]}}
   };
Grid@Table[
  StreamPlot[
   expressions[[i, j]] /. k -> 1, {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, 
    range}, PlotLabel -> MatrixForm@{expressions[[i, j]]}],
  {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}
  ]
```

[image]

I added the small angle approximation of the harmonic oscillator as well for comparison.

My interpretation: as long as $x$ and $y$ are both small the approximation is valid. The region of validity is fairly small though and outside the unit circle the approximation becomes pretty bad. The valid region will probably change for different $k$.

Comment: When writing thr ODE, to be notationally consistent, you should write \begin{align}
\pmatrix{\dot x\\\dot y}=\pmatrix{y\\-y^2\sin x-k^2x\cos x}. 
\end{align}
And as you've noted in the end, the origin is an equilibrium point, which is why one can consider expanding the RHS around this point.

Comment: @peek-a-boo oops my bad, made a typo while copying.

Answer (score 2):

To think about the problem physically, we can imagine differential equations with the same dimensionality as linear force problems.  Your idealized approximation $\ddot\theta≈-k^2\theta$ is the [frequently useful](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159096/44126) simple harmonic oscillator, given by a Hooke’s Law-type of linear restoring force. In linear coordinates, we would write this force like $m\vec a\propto - \vec x$.

What are some interactions that correspond to the term you’d like to approximate as zero?  Consider that

$$
m\vec a\propto -\vec v
$$

is usually considered a “drag” force, acting to bring the velocity towards zero.  In one sense we can already stop there: if you approximated $\dot\theta\to0$, you are eliminating some kind of a drag term from your equation, and turning a damped oscillator into an undamped oscillator.

Yours is not the usual damped oscillator, because the directionality comes from the position, not from the squared velocity:

$$
m\vec a ≈ -v^2\vec x
$$

A related remark: when you’re approximating by throwing away terms, you don’t generally want to say “this term should go to zero.” It’s better hygiene to say “*this* term is much smaller than *that* term,” which is a reason to keep only “*that* term.” You’ve already done this with your small angle approximation, which is

$$
\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots≈1
$$

and which is justified in the limit $x^2\ll 1$, whether $x\to0$ or not.  The distinction between “much smaller than” versus “near zero” is especially important if you do some algebra and find that you actually have $1-\cos x$, in which case you need to be prepared to go back and re-do your approximation with more terms.

In this case, you have (in the linear-force language),

$$
m\vec a = -(v^2+k^2)\vec x
$$

and the relevant comparison is whether $v^2\ll k^2$ (or vice-versa).  You might remember that a simple harmonic oscillator has its minimum $v$ when $x$ is large, and its maximum $v$ as $x$ passes through the origin.  So the question of whether you can ignore $\dot\theta^2$ and treat your oscillator as undamped is a question which depends both on your spring constant $k$ and on your amplitude.  The damping becomes negligible if the oscillations are small and the spring is stiff.

Specifically, since the maximum speed for an undamped oscillator is $\dot\theta_\text{max}=k\theta_\text{max}$, you have

$$
\frac{\dot\theta_\text{max}^2}{k^2} ≈ \theta_\text{max}^2 
$$

which you have *already assumed* was small, in order to use the small-angle approximation.

An exercise for the reader: while you can ignore the damping over a *single* oscillation, you can’t ignore the damping over *many* oscillations. How many? My ballpark guess is $1/\theta_\text{max}$ or $1/\theta_\text{max}^2$, but I would expect to learn something from constructing the argument. The square would make a big difference in estimating the dissipation time of small oscillations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mathematical justification for setting $\dot \theta^2$ to $0$. If this equation represents some specific physical system and if it is known for physical reasons that $\dot \theta^2 \approx 0$ then it could be justified. But that will require a specific physical argument for the specific system in question, not a generic mathematical justification.

Comment: This is not true; the mathematical justification is that it the origin (in velocity-phase space) is an equilibrium point for the ODE, so it makes sense to consider this aporoximation. We're simply linearizing (in the multivariable sense) an ODE about a known solution, and this is a purely mathematical question requiring zero physical input. Stability of the equilibrium point is of course a separate issue requiring more analysis, but again that doesn't require physical input (sure knowing the physics setup could help with predicting answers quicker, but it's not strictly necessary).