# Need help finding Hamiltonian for equations of motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, differential-equations, complex-systems

I have the following equation of motion:
$$\ddot \theta+\dot\theta^2\theta+k^2\theta=0.\tag 1$$
This equation is from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748837/93729). I wanted to see if I could find a Hamiltonian for this equation but I'm not even sure if it is possible. As an ansatz I postulated that the conjugate momentum is $p=\dot\theta$. This gives the following coupled equations:
\begin{align}
\dot\theta&=p\tag 2\\
\dot p&=-p^2\theta-k^2\theta.\tag 3
\end{align}
We expect the Hamiltons equations to hold so
\begin{align}
\dot\theta=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p},\quad
\dot p=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}.\tag 4
\end{align}
From (2) we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}&=p\tag 5\\
H&=\int p\,\mathrm dp+f(\theta)\tag 6\\
H&=\tfrac 1 2p^2+f(\theta).\tag 7
\end{align}
From (3) we get
\begin{align}
-\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta}&=-p^2\theta-k^2\theta\tag 8\\
H&=\int (p^2\theta +k^2\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta+g(p)\tag 9\\
H&=\tfrac 1 2(p^2+k^2)\theta^2+g(p).\tag{10}
\end{align}

Combining these two expressions gives
$$H(\theta,p)=\tfrac 1 2p^2+\tfrac 1 2(p^2+k^2)\theta^2.\tag{11}$$
But this expression doesn't give the right equations of motion back; it fails for $\dot\theta=p+p\theta^2\neq p$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. The ansatz (2) is too optimistic: The generalized velocity $\dot{\theta}$ is not necessarily the canonical momentum.
2. Instead use the method outlined in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/432672/2451) to find a Hamiltonian formulation.

Comment: Thanks, your answer in (2) is what I was looking for!